# wagtail customized admin panels

Tags: admin, wagtail, wagtail-admin

is there a way of customizing my own admin panel , not in terms of styling. What i wish to achieve is a analytics tab , similar to [wagalytics](https://github.com/tomdyson/wagalytics) . The issue im having with wagalytics is that it is using google analytics , and google analytics is blocked by most adblockers and Mozilla fire fox , making the data really unreliable. As such i wish to utitlize other services like [django-analytical](https://github.com/jazzband/django-analytical) to my wagtail administration page with a graph similar to that of wagalytics . However , i have not yet found any resources online that teaches me to override the admin and create my own customized panel (different from the customized tabs [here](https://learnwagtail.com/tutorials/custom-admin-tabs/) ).

Could someone point me towards the right direction?

Comment: Are you trying to make a panel appear on editing pages? Or a page within admin that is available by the side menu on the left.

Comment: as a side menu on the left , i am looking through wagtailmodeladmins as of now (seems like its what i need)

Comment: To modify the side menu you need to use a hook. https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#admin-modules modeladmin is for creating a CRUD style interface to existing models.

Comment: Do you have a package or something installable? Because I am looking for a alternative for google analytics and I cannot believe that nobody had this idea before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a page (link) to the Wagtail admin menu, you can use the hook [`register_admin_menu_item`](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/hooks.html#register-admin-menu-item).

Create a file `my-app/wagtail_hooks.py` and this will be run by Wagtail to hook in custom functionality.

```py
rom django.urls import reverse

from wagtail.core import hooks
from wagtail.admin.menu import MenuItem

@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_frank_menu_item():
  return MenuItem('Frank', reverse('name-of-analytics-url'), classnames='icon icon-folder-inverse', order=10000)
```

You will need to set up the view with whatever reporting/graphs yourself, you could look into the source of `wagalytics` or simply serve whatever reporting `django-analytics` makes available.

If you want the templates your view use to extend the Wagtail admin templates, you can do this using the `wagtailadmin/base.html`. e.g. `{% extends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}`. Note: you may need to add `'wagtail.admin',` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.